# How to show JLabel ellipsis in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

Using the default layout manager, the JLabel shows its ellipsis when the frame is resized.

As illustrated by:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("JLabel, show me your ellipsis!");

    jFrame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Sure darling! Shrink me and I'll show you"));

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

However, MigLayout does not display such behaviour!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("JLabel, show me your ellipsis!");

    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Nope! I just do not know you well enough!"));

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I tried all the layout/component constraint I could think of. Does anybody know if such thing is even possible in Mig?

Comment: +1 for a hilarious example, you made me lol with your code sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JLabel has a minimum size that is roughly (or exactly, don't remember) the same as its preferred size. MigLayout only shrinks a component down to its min. So you have to add a component constraint that allows sizing smaller than its minSize:

```
content.add(label, "wmin 10lp");
```